# I have two wallpapers (side by side) on one screen. help!

Tags: screen, desktop-background

I have been messing around with my Ubuntu , I had duplicated my screen to show up on my TV. After this I decided to just go back to my laptop screen, Ubuntu did this, however, Ubuntu now shows two wallpapers side by side on my laptop screen.

So for example I can drag the Chrome Browser all the way to the far right of the second wallpaper screen.

My resolution is 1920 x 1080, so this set up gives me two wallpapers side by side with this resolution.

I don't want this, has anybody any idea on how to fix this issue.

To be clear, I am only wanting the normal one screen wallpaper.

Thanks for any help.
Asim

Comment: Try changing it and select the old one again.

Answer (score 0):

Your question isn't very clear and is hard to understand. Ubuntu by default will only use one wallpaper for each screen. If you go to "System Settings" -> "Appearance". You will find all of your wallpaper settings.

Note: most of the wallpapers have a max resolution of 2048 x 1280.

It's hard to answer your questions since I can't replicate the issue, Ubuntu by default uses one wallpaper for all screens. I know KDE by default has a different wallpaper per screen, so you will need to change the wallpaper explicitly for each screen.

[Here is a related thread.](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1861037)

Maybe if you reverse engineer the instructions on that post you can solve your issue.